# How to get key of random chosen object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm choosing a random element from an array of objects and I don't know how to get the key of that returned value. My object looks like this:

```js
{
    "location": "LA",
    "id": "34",
    "prizes": {
        "1": {
            "prize": "Prize 1",
            "quantity": "6",
            "extracted": ""
        },
        "3": {
            "prize": "Prize 3",
            "quantity": "10",
            "extracted": ""
        },
        "4": {
            "prize": "Prize 4",
            "quantity": "10",
            "extracted": ""
        }
    }
}
```

An my code where I choose random is this:

```html
var prizes_by_locations = locations[id_prizes].prizes;
var final_prizes = [];

for(var x in prizes_by_locations){
  final_prizes.push(prizes_by_locations[x]);
}

var prize = final_prizes[Math.floor(Math.random()*final_prizes.length)];

//here is the random chosen prize but I need to get the key too
var chosen_prize = prize.prize;
```

I also have to say that I first remove some elements, that's why the keys are 1, 3, 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the other way: select a random key from the object, then you can easily also get the value:

```
var prizes_by_locations = locations[id_prizes].prizes;
var keys = Object.keys(prizes_by_locations);
var prize_key = keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0];
var prize_value = prizes_by_locations[prize_key];
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you correctly and the randomKey variable is what you need
    var prizes_by_locations = locations[id_prizes].prizes;
    var final_prizes = [];

```
for(var x in prizes_by_locations){
  final_prizes.push(prizes_by_locations[x]);
}
var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random()*final_prizes.length);
var prize = final_prizes[randomKey];

//here is the random chosen prize but I need to get the key too
var chosen_prize = prize.prize;
alert('The key is:' + randomKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var prizes_by_locations = locations[id_prizes].prizes;
var final_prizes = [];
var keys = []

for(var x in prizes_by_locations){
  final_prizes.push({
       key: x,
       result: prizes_by_locations[x]);
}
}

var prize = final_prizes[Math.floor(Math.random()*final_prizes.length)];

//here is the random chosen prize but I need to get the key too
var chosen_prize = prize.result.prize;
var key = prize.key;
```